# Quarkus: perform SQL command on each DB connection

Tags: sql, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Is there any way to perform SQL command on every SQL reactive connection in Quarkus?
Like in Spring:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql= SET aurora_replica_read_consistency = 'session'
```